# Extract zip contents into directory with same name as zip file, retain directory structure

Tags: batch-file, scripting, 7zip

I would like to write a bat script to do the following:

Use 7 Zip to extract files from an existing zip file, into a folder by the same name as the original zip file (bar the .zip extension), and keeping the file & directory structure that was contained in the zip file.

I can extract all the same files into the current directory, by using

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" e  myZipFile.zip
```

Comment: @Harriet On using 7-Zip from command line it is always advisable to open help of 7-Zip - the file `7-zip.chm` in program files folder of 7-Zip - and read in help on tab __Contents__ the pages listed under list item *Command Line Version*. The commands `e` and `x` are both explained in help as well as all other commands and switches. You would have just needed to read the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading the help of the `7z`-command by just typing `"C:\Path To\7-Zip\7z.exe"` gets the help with all possible arguments. Here we find the following interesting ones:

```
 e : Extract files from archive (without using directory names)
```

and

```
x : eXtract files with full paths
```

Trial and error shows that the latter is the one fitting your desired behaviour without bigger effort :)

After the comment by [@BadmintonCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356105/badmintoncat) here is the addition that will create a folder to zip everything into (use as batch script with the file as argument):

```
@echo off

SET "filename=%~1"
SET dirName=%filename:~0,-4%

7z x -o"%dirName%" "%filename%"
```

From the help: `-o{Directory} : set Output directory`. 7z will create the directory if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 8):

Just use the command: `7z x *.zip -o\*`

Comment: I'm not sure that's going to do what he wants. The `-o` option needs a specific directory named. Using `-o\*` is either going to expand to all files (and probably error) or it will create a directory actually named `*` (also not what he wants).

Comment: Replace `*.zip` with actual name of the zip file and it works great. `7z e yourfile.zip -o\*`

Comment: `find . -name "*.zip" -exec 7z x "{}" -o\* \;`
based on the answer and comments