# How to extract archives from dir/subdir/*.* to dir/%zipname%/

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, archive, 7zip

I have a bunch of Archives that I want to extract. Problem is, there's a lot of them, and it's a lot of info to move around. I'd like to do it all at once. It's probably taken more time to research than to do it manually, but research is more interesting.

TL;DR: Would like help with 7-zip command line to extract multiple archives into their own directory. Autohotkey, Powershell, and batch files answers would also be nice if you are feeling extra helpful.

**Win10**, latest update and all that. I've been using **7-zip**, so if there's a better extractor for this it might be a helpful suggestion. I have a little experience with coding, so I can usually pars an example and apply it to my project, but I can't come up with code on my own. So with that said, I'm comfortable using **cmd**, **autohotkey**, **powershell**, **batch files**, and a few others, but I need an example before I can do anything. haha

So, in my research, I found 
*(7z x -o"...\Stellaris\mod\Examples\" "...\content\281990\*")*
for **cmd**, which works, except that extracts everything to the same dir since the archive files are in the root archive dir (I think that's why; if they were one folder down, it should work like I want right?). I don't *think* you can use environment variables in the path(?). Not sure what would make it work here...

**Powershell**: I only recently started tinkering with it so the one script I found didn't make any sense to me. And never found anyone using **AutoHotKey** for this.

And finally a **batch file* I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932553/extract-zip-contents-into-directory-with-same-name-as-zip-file-retain-directory) seemed to come closest (normally I'd comment on that thread cause apparently it's still active, but I don't have 50 rep), but I wasn't sure how to modify it for my purposes:

---

@echo off

SET "filename=%~1"           `#Where does the working dir path go?`

SET dirName=%filename:~0,-4% `#How/where would you put in wildcards?`

7z x -o"%dirName%" "%filename%"

---

I don't mind using any method, though I might prefer **AHK**? I'm probably most experienced there.

If you made it this far, wow, I'm impressed! I hope it was coherent enough to understand (probably not at first?). And maybe a little entertaining? ***I*** think I'm funny. Let me know if I should add or remove anything for the future. I know it's probably way too much context, but I would rather have too much than not enough, and I'm never sure what would be relevant and what would not. I'm not happy with my code format here, but I didn't quite understand what the help was saying about whitespace and I'm not familiar enough with Markdown yet (I wanted comments to be in line). Also, I'm honestly not sure about the tags.

EDIT: Added TL;DR at the top, and...

**Found an answer** via a program that does this. I'll post it in an answer as well: [ExtractNow](https://www.extractnow.com) seems to be a bit outdated, last update was in '17, but it did what I wanted it to.

Comment: As it stands this question is too broad for this site, since this is a question and answer place about specific coding issues. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer via a program that does this. [ExtractNow](https://www.extractnow.com/#/home) seems to be a bit outdated, last update was in '17, but it did what I wanted it to with only a few settings changes.

Answer (score 0):

For interactive use at the command prompt:

```
for %z in ("\path\to\dir\subdir\*.zip") do @echo 7z "-o\path\to\extracted\%~nz" "%~z"
```

This won't run 7z, but it will print out the commands. Once you are satisfied that the printed commands look fine, remove the `@echo` to execute them.

In a batch script you must of course duplicate the `%` signs.

Answer (score 0):

> So, in my research, I found
> *(7z x -o"...\Stellaris\mod\Examples" "...\content\281990\*")*
> for **cmd**, which works, except that extracts everything to the same dir...

Assuming you were using Windows, 7-zip would have worked fine to do what you wanted. The only thing you were missing is the `*` character, which 7-zip expands to be the archive name when used with the `-o` switch:

```
 7z x "dir\subdir\*.*"  -o"dir\*"
```

So *7z x -o"...\Stellaris\mod\Examples" "...\content\281990\*"*
becomes:

```
7z x -o"...\Stellaris\mod\Examples\*" "...\content\281990\*"
```

Also be aware that `*.*` does *not* mean any file under 7-zip. 7-Zip takes `*.*` to be name of any file that has an extension. To process all files just use a `"dir\subdir\*"` without the extra `.*`.